# Serial communication

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am developing an application in C# that needs to communicate with a matrix switch through serial communication.

```
string value = "abc";
serialPort1.Open();
serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 500;
serialPort1.WriteLine(value);
serialPort1.Close();
```

The matrix box's state is supposed to change upon `WriteLine(value)`.

Here is my problem. When I send the string value, the matrix box's state does not change. However, when I send the same string via Putty (through serial communication), the matrix box responds correctly. All serial properties are identical (BaudRate, DataBits, PortName, etc).

What are some possible solutions I should try?

Comment: FYI: The WriteLine() method does append a carriage return (hex 0x0D) to the data sent on the line. We use SerialPort.Write and convert to hex values prior to send, but this may be more complicated if your commands/replies are guaranteed to be ascci, unicode, or another encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Can you post your code where you setup your `SerialPort`? You have to make sure *all* properties are as your matrix switch expects. For instance:

```
// Setup port
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
serialPort.PortName = portName; //eg. COM1
serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
serialPort.DataBits = 8;
serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
serialPort.NewLine = "\r\n";
serialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
serialPort.WriteTimeout = 1000;
```

After you have called `Open()` on your port you can check the open or closed status with the `serialPort.IsOpen` property.

Answer (score 2):

Download PortMon http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx and run successful serial communication using Putty, sniffing all data exchange between PC and device. Then execute your program and compare exchange logs. This should give you the answer, what is done incorrect in your program.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the Encoding property on the serial port.  It looks like the default is ASCII.  Maybe your device is expecting Unicode?